# Storing data from query in $_SESSION

Tags: php, session

I've looked everywhere but most solutions are outdated or confusing.

After a user's email and passwords match, their name and id are also saved then they are sent to their homepage.

```
  <?php

session_start();
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "projectinnovations");

//Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL:" . mysqli_connect_errno();
}

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
{
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']);

    $email = stripslashes($email);
    $password = stripslashes($password);
    $sql="SELECT * FROM individual_users WHERE email='$email' and password='$password'";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($count==1)
    {
        $_SESSION['email']= $email;
        $_SESSION['password']= $password;
        $sql1="SELECT fullname FROM individual_users WHERE email='$email' and password='$password'";
        $result1=mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
        $_SESSION['fullname']= mysqli_fetch($result1);
        $sql2="SELECT id FROM individual_users WHERE email='$email' and password='$password'";
        $result2=mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
        $_SESSION['id']= mysqli_fetch($result2);
        header("location:home.php");
    }

    else 
    {
        header("location:login.php");
    }
}
 mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: did you start the session? doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: What is the questions?

Comment: sorry. let me add all the code @Fred-ii-

Comment: I did @VictorSmirnov. There is all the code

Answer (score 0):

In order to make dealing with the session possible add `session_start();` to the top of your script.

Answer (score 0):

## You haven't started the session

The simple answer is that you need to put `session_start()` at the top of the script (and the top of any script that uses the session variables).

### But really, you don't need to do this...

The better answer is that what you're doing looks dangerously like relying on globals, and there's no reason to keep things like user e-mail addresses as global variables. Consider taking another look at your application architecture to see *why* you need to do this.

### What could you do instead?

You'd be better off creating a `User` class which has the variables you need, then creating an instance of that class whenever you need access to user data.

If your worry is database congestion, look into [memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) or [APCu](https://pecl.php.net/package/APCu) to lighten the load.

### Other issues

If this is real code, you should be using [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to handle login. Currently, you are storing passwords in plaintext, free for any hacker to look at.

You should also look into [binding parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) in queries, which would allow you to avoid having to think about escaping values before running queries.

Comment: Sorry @Matt Prelude. Here is all the code. I did start the session but all your other points are very valid. Do you have any solution with the new edited version?

Comment: @LM23 What was the issue?

Comment: I didn't convert result into a string, making it unstorable as a string.